# Concatenate multiple column strings into one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe with firstname and surname. I want to create a column `fullname`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'firstname':['jack','john','donald'],
                  'lastname':[pd.np.nan,'obrien','trump']})

print(df1)

  firstname lastname
0      jack      NaN
1      john   obrien
2    donald    trump
```

This works if there are no `NaN` values:

```
df1['fullname'] = df1['firstname']+df1['lastname']
```

However since there are `NaNs` in my dataframe, I decided to cast to `string` first. But it causes a problem in the `fullname` column:

```
df1['fullname'] = str(df1['firstname'])+str(df1['lastname'])


  firstname lastname                                           fullname
0      jack      NaN  0      jack\n1      john\n2    donald\nName: f...
1      john   obrien  0      jack\n1      john\n2    donald\nName: f...
2    donald    trump  0      jack\n1      john\n2    donald\nName: f...
```

I can write some function that checks for nans and inserts the data into the new frame, but before I do that - is there another fast method to combine these strings into one column?

Answer (score 3):

You need to treat `NaN`s using **[`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)** Here, you can fill it with `''` .

```
df1['fullname'] = df1['firstname'] + ' ' +df1['lastname'].fillna('')
```

Output:

```
 firstname  lastname    fullname
0   jack    NaN         jack
1   john    obrien      john obrien
2   donald  trump       donald trumpt
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `.add` and specify a `fill_value`

```
df1.firstname.add(" ").add(df1.lastname, fill_value="")
```

---

PS: Chaining too many adds or `+` is not recommended for strings, but for one or two columns you should be fine

Comment: Agreed and +1, `+` is not good for chaining. It is *workable* solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`df1['fullname'] = df1['firstname']+df1['lastname'].fillna('')`

Comment: might be safe to include the fillna on the firstname column as well but hard to say without the complete data

Answer (score 0):

There is also [`Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) which can handle `NaN` and includes the separator.

```py
df1["fullname"] = df1["firstname"].str.cat(df1["lastname"], sep=" ", na_rep="")

   firstname lastname      fullname
 0      jack      NaN         jack
 1      john   obrien   john obrien
 2    donald    trump  donald trump
```

Answer (score 0):

What I will do (For the case more than two columns need to join)

```
df1.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
Out[57]: 
0            jack
1     john obrien
2    donald trump
dtype: object
```